# Not able to receive XMPPPubsub events to node subscribers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp, publish-subscribe, xmppframework

I am developing an app like RSS Feeds. I want users to get feeds without calling any web service. I read out some documents and got a solution of using XMPP where XMPPPubsub gives us that functionality to send an event notification to all subscribers.

In XMPPPubsub Owner creates a node and other users who want to get event notification subscribes to that node.

1. Set up XMPPPubsub

   ```
   XMPPJID *serviceJID =[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"pubsub.%@",HOST_NAME]];
   _xmppPubSub = [[XMPPPubSub alloc]initWithServiceJID:serviceJID     dispatchQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
   [_xmppPubSub addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
   [_xmppPubSub activate:_xmppStream];
   ```
2. Creation of Node

   ```
   - (void)createNodeWithName:(NSString*)nodeName withCompletionHandler:(CreateNodeCompletionHandler)completionBlock{

      _createNodeCompletionHandler = completionBlock;

      [_xmppPubSub createNode:nodeName withOptions:@{@"pubsub#title":nodeName,@"pubsub#deliver_notifications":@"1",@"pubsub#deliver_payloads":@"0",@"pubsub#persist_items":@"1",@"pubsub#notify_sub":@"1",@"pubsub#subscribe":@"1",@"pubsub#send_last_published_item":@"When a new subscription is processed and whenever a subscriber comes online",@"pubsub#access_model":@"open",@"pubsub#presence_based_delivery":@"1",@"pubsub#publish_model":@"open"}];
   }
   ```
3. User who wants to have events must subscribe to node

   ```
   - (void)subScribeToNode:(NSString*)nodeName withCompletionHandler:(SubscribeNodeCompletionHandler)completionBlock{

     _subscribeNodeCompletionHandler = completionBlock;
     [_xmppPubSub subscribeToNode:nodeName withJID:_xmppStream.myJID options: @{ @"pubsub#deliver"      : @(YES),
                                                                   @"pubsub#digest"       : @(YES),
                                                                    @"pubsub#include_body" : @(YES),
                                                                    @"pubsub#show-values"  : @[ @"chat", @"online", @"away" ] }];
    }
   ```
4. Publish the event to node

   ```
   - (void)sendMessage:(NSString*)message ToNode:(NSString*)node{
   NSXMLElement *body = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"body"];
   [body setStringValue:message];

   NSXMLElement *messageBody = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"message"];
   [messageBody setXmlns:@"jabber:client"];
   [messageBody addChild:body];
   [_xmppPubSub publishToNode:node entry:messageBody withItemID:nil options:@{@"pubsub#access_model":@"open"}];
   }
   ```

All is working well Users are able to subscribe to a node. We are able to create the Node. When we get our subscriber nodes, it also returns all the nodes. The events that we published are also there in Database and if I retrieve events by code it also returns all of them.

But the issue is the subscribers are not able to get its notification in **didReceiveMessage** so subscribers are not getting notified of events.

No logs in below functions

```
    - (void)xmppPubSub:(XMPPPubSub *)sender didReceiveMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message{
  NSLog(@" -----We Just Received message wooo hooo whow owowhwo -----");
}
    - (BOOL)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didReceiveIQ:(XMPPIQ *)iq{
    return YES;
}
```

Please guide me through this what I am doing wrong in it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi hares. did you solve your issue ? I am also facing same issue.. Please have a look into it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115144/ios-xmpp-pubsub-not-receiving-events-while-publishing-node-to-my-subscribed-user

Answer (score 0):

Client should indicate he wishes to receive notifications, as described in [XEP-0060](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html#filtered-notifications)

In XMPPFramework you need to implement `XMPPCapabilitiesDelegate` and add `younodename+notify` to client capabilities. E.g. in your `XMPPModule` you need the following:

```
- (BOOL)activate:(XMPPStream *)aXmppStream
{
    if ([super activate:aXmppStream])
    {
        [xmppStream autoAddDelegate:self delegateQueue:moduleQueue toModulesOfClass:[XMPPCapabilities class]];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
- (NSArray *)myFeaturesForXMPPCapabilities:(XMPPCapabilities *)sender
{
    return @["myprotocolnode+notify"];
}
```

Comment: It will become static for only one node. But i want to receive notifications from all nods which are subscribed by me.

Comment: So you can query list of subscribed nodes and advertise +notify for each. Maybe you can configure some pubsub server component to make notifications enabled by default, but it is not recommended.

Comment: And in xmppModule class if we use XMPPCapabilities it gives forward class declaration error. As XMPPModule is superclass of XMPPCapabilities

Comment: you need to import XMPPCapabilites.h in your XMPPFramework.h

Comment: I do have it already there. I already have _xmppCapabilities = [[XMPPCapabilities alloc] initWithCapabilitiesStorage:_xmppCapabilitiesStorage]; in Setupstream

Comment: myFeaturesForXMPPCapabilities is never getting called

Comment: You did not activate your own module or XMPPCapabilities module

Comment: I had activated just after initializing capabilities object with     [_xmppCapabilities      activate:_xmppStream];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87455/discussion-between-haresh-and-vitalyster).