# XmppFramework: How to register user as subscribers

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

i have a node created with this code:

```
xmppPubSub?.createNode(name, withOptions: ["pubsub#notification_type": "normal", "pubsub#send_last_published_item": "never", "pubsub#publish_model" : "open", "pubsub#max_items" : "1000000"])
```

anyone can write, how can i do to user "pubsub#publish_model" : "publishers"? i want to enable only some user to write to the node, how can i do?

Thanks!

Comment: hi which one framework you talking about ? and what you tried to add users in pubusb node ?

Comment: The framework is xmppframework https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework

Comment: did you try something from here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115144/ios-xmpp-pubsub-not-receiving-events-while-publishing-node-to-my-subscribed-user

Comment: I didn't find the doc for this!!! I use subscribepubsubnode but it works only with publish_model open

Comment: yes i have done pubsub related all things on android

Comment: Can you post sample code!? Are you using publishers as mode!??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122635/discussion-between-saveen-and-luca-becchetti).

Answer (score 0):

hi please check below code how to subscribe node and how we can get payload message, whenever somebody subscribed user sending something.Moreover taking overview from xmpp official site from [here](http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0060.html).

```
LeafNode XMPP_PUB_SUB_LEAF;
SimplePayload item = null;
LeafNode node;


class ItemEventCoordinator implements ItemEventListener {
    @Override
    public void handlePublishedItems(ItemPublishEvent items) {

        Log.e("tag", "ItemPublishEvent ::" + items.getItems());

    }
}


PubSubManager mgr = new PubSubManager(XMPP.getInstance()
                    .getConnection(acitiviy));
//  ConfigureForm form = new ConfigureForm(FormType.submit);
//  form.setAccessModel(AccessModel.open);
//  form.setDeliverPayloads(true);
//  form.setNotifyRetract(true);
//  form.setPersistentItems(true);
//  form.setPublishModel(PublishModel.open);
try {
//  LeafNode leaf = (LeafNode) mgr
//  .createNode("ABC", form);
LeafNode leaf = (LeafNode) mgr.getNode("ABC");
leaf.addItemEventListener(new ItemEventCoordinator());  
//leaf.getSubscriptionOptions(XMPP.getInstance().getConnection(acitiviy)
// .getUser());

//leaf.unsubscribe(XMPP.getInstance().getConnection(acitiviy)
//.getUser());

leaf.subscribe(XMPP.getInstance().getConnection(acitiviy)
                        .getUser());

leaf.send(new PayloadItem(XMPP.getInstance().getConnection(acitiviy)
                        .getUser(),
                        new SimplePayload("Online", "stage:pubsub:simple",
                                "<book xmlns='pubsub:test:book'>   <title>Online</title></book>")));

for (int i = 0; i < leaf.getAffiliations().size(); i++) {

    Log.d("tag", "getAffiliations 111::"
                            + leaf.getAffiliations().get(i)
                                    .getElementName());

}

for (int i = 0; i < leaf.getSubscriptions().size(); i++) {

                    // Log.e("tag", "getSubscriptions 111::"
                    // + leaf.getSubscriptions().get(i).getJid());

}

try {
 List<Subscription> listSubs = mgr.getSubscriptions();
                    for (int i = 0; i < listSubs.size(); i++) {

// Log.e("tag", "Subscription ::"
// + listSubs.get(i).getJid());

}
} catch (XMPPException e) {
System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Thanks hope this will help you understand pubsub.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution, i have to post a stream like this:

```
<iq type='set'
    from='hamlet@denmark.lit/elsinore'
    to='pubsub.shakespeare.lit'
    id='ent2'>
  <pubsub xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/pubsub#owner'>
    <affiliations node='princely_musings'>
      <affiliation jid='bard@shakespeare.lit' affiliation='publisher'/>
    </affiliations>
  </pubsub>
</iq>
```